# Rails grouped_coolection_select using Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, mongoid3

I am having an issue with the grouped_collection_select using Mongoid. Error message I am getting is: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol).

I am using rails 3.2.12 & latest version of Mongoid.

Here is my code:

```
class States
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :_id
  field :name
  field :abbreviation
  field :countryId

  belongs_to :countries
end

class Countries
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :_id
  field :name
  field :abbreviation

  has_many :states
end

<div class="field"> 
  <%= f.label :_id, "Country" %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :_id, Countries.order_by([:name, :asc]), :_id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :_id, "State or Province" %><br />
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:states, :countryId, Countries.order_by([:name, :asc]), :states, :name, :id, :name) %>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try this: `<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:state_id, Countries.order_by([:name, :asc]), :states, :name, :id, :name) %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `f.grouped_collection_select` which implies that the first parameter will be inferred from `f.object`.  Removing your first parameter and changing the second to the column name of the field that you want it to be saved to should solve your issue

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:state, Countries.order_by([:name, :asc]), :states, :name, :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I implemented your change but now I get this error message: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `state' for #<Equipment:0x007fcdc29bf798>). Any thoughts on how to resolve? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to change `:state` in my answer to the field name where you want to save the selected state.  without any knowledge where you use the form, we won't have any idea what the field name is.

Comment: hi jvnill, can you please provide a small example of what the field name would be to save the selected state? thanks!

Comment: where are you using this form? for what model?  chekc that model and change `:state` to the column name where you want to save the selected state.

Comment: hi jvnill, First, thanks for the help! I am using the following model: class Equipment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :description
  field :modelNumber
  field :title
  field :categoryId
  field :subCategoryId
  field :state_id

end      I would like to save the id of the state as state_id. here is my adjusted controller control: <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:state_id, Countries.order_by([:name, :asc]), :states, :name, :id, :name) %> I am now getting a uninitialized constant State error. Any help would be appreciated.